# É possível usar o strcmp para checar diferentes linhas de um arquivo?

Tags: c, banco-de-dados, c++, crud

Estou com o seguinte problema: o código é para um programa que permita diferentes usuários fazerem seus cadastros e login. Acontece que, sendo bem direto, não sei como manter a parte do "diferentes usuários". Uma vez que adiciono o primeiro, somente ele consegue logar, pela forma como minha função de login funciona. Eu consegui adicionar diferentes usuários ao arquivo e separa-los por linhas, mas preciso fazer com que a função login seja capaz de verificar linha por linha até encontrar o usuário e senhas corretos antes de rejeita-lo. Alguém pode me ajudar nisso? A função cadastro:

```
void cadastrar_user() {
FILE *fp;
struct usuario_t usuario;
int i = 1;
memset(&usuario,0,sizeof(struct usuario_t));

printf("\n ----Cadastro de usuario----");
printf("\n\n Insira um login> ");
scanf("%s", &usuario.login);
printf("\n Insira uma senha> ");
scanf("%s", &usuario.senha);

fp = fopen("login", "a+");
fwrite(&usuario, sizeof(struct usuario_t), 1, fp);
fputs("\n", fp);
fclose(fp);
printf("\n");
printf("\n ---- Usuario cadastrado, redirecionando para login! ----");
login();
```

}

A função login:

```
int login(){
FILE *fp;
struct usuario_t usuario;
fp = fopen("login","rb");
memset(&usuario, 0, sizeof(struct usuario_t));

fread(&usuario, sizeof(struct usuario_t), 1, fp);
fclose(fp);
if(!strcmp("", usuario.login)){
printf("\n ----Cadastro nao encontrado, redirecionando para cadastro!----\n");
cadastrar_user();}

 else {
        char login[LOGIN_MAX];
        char senha[SENHA_MAX];
        printf("\n Login> ");
        scanf("%s", &login);
        printf(" Senha> ");
        scanf("%s", &senha);

        if (!strcmp(login, usuario.login) && !strcmp(senha, usuario.senha)) {
            printf("\n Bem vindo %s!\n", usuario.login);
            menu_crud();
        }

        else {
            printf(" \n----Usuario ou senha invalidos!----\n");
            printf("\n  Tente novamente! Redirecionando para a pagina inicial\n\n");
            main();
        }
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Use um banco de dados. Veja por exemplo [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html).

Comment: Eu poderia e tenho certeza que seria melhor. Mas isso é um projeto da minha faculdade, e precisa ser feito através de arquivo.

Answer (score -1):

você colocou o comando fputs para quebrar a linha no arquivo , mas creio que causa algum bug , e removendo , funcionou bem , e também você pode colocar um loop para procurar em todo o arquivo , que poderia ser assim :

```
while (fread(&usuario, sizeof(usuario_t), 1, fp) != 0)
{
    flg = 0;
    printf("\nCadastro %d\n\
            \rnome --: %s\n\
            \rSenha -: %s\n",
            cont            ,
            usuario.login   ,
            usuario.senha  );
    if ( ! strcmp( login, usuario.login ) && ! strcmp( senha , usuario.senha ) )
    {
        flg = 1;
        break;
    }
    cont++;
}
fclose(fp);
if(flg)
{
    printf("\n Bem vindo %s!\n", usuario.login);
    menu_crud();
}
else 
{
    printf(" \n----Usuario ou senha invalidos!----\n");
    printf("\n  Tente novamente! Redirecionando para a pagina inicial\n\n");
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Na verdade, ele não funciona com o fputs e nem sem ele, haha. Mas preferi coloca-lo porquê dessa maneira eu consigo visualizar que o código está indo em alguma direção. Inicialmente eu pensei em criar diferentes arquivos para diferentes usuários e dai eu poderia fazer a minha função login checar todos eles e etc, mas o fopen simplesmente nao comporta uma syntax do tipo fopen(("%d", i), wb). Tentei aplicar seu código no meu agora mas não consegui fazer ele funcionar corretamente. Vou continuar tentando.